# Dropbox Datastore API, how to show username?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying the Dropbox's Datastore API(JavaScript), but I don't know how to get username. I've tried something like this:

```
var account = new Dropbox.AccountInfo();
console.log('getAInfo' + account.getAccountInfo());
```

and I got this message in my console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display_name' of undefined".

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have a `Dropbox.Client` object. To fetch the account info, do this:

```
client.getAccountInfo(function (error, info) {
    console.log('Name: ' + info.name);
});
```